# Disable URL /web/guest/home in liferay

Tags: apache, liferay

Whan any user is hitting url 
`http://abc.xyz.com/web/12345/home`  Liferay Welcome page is coming up where user can see options like calender, language, dictionary etc. I am using Liferay 5.2.3. Can anyone suggest me how to disable this URL?
Can the URL be blocked from Apache?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to a user's personal page - this is a public page and you can configure Liferay so that users don't have personal (public) pages. As long as the users have personal and public pages, they are, well, public: If you navigate to them, you'll get to see them. You can make them private pages (thus the URL will change to `/group/12345/home`) and - at least - require a login. But as long as you have a public page in your portal, it will be shown.

(You can also change permissions on every single page, but that's probably what you also don't want)

Can you block on apache level? Yes. But why change at the entry point when you can also get rid of the root cause - e.g. properly configure the pages and access levels.

Also, Liferay 5.2.3 is quite ancient now. You should really consider to upgrade

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Currently i have my pages as private and if any user hits the url "/group/12345/home" in his browser after authentication, he can access those public pages. I have already changed the settings of private pages but nothing is working. Can you suggest what to do?@olaf Kock

Comment: I am considering an upgrade but till then  first need to fix this issue in production ;)

Comment: /web/12345 points to a public page. /group/12345 would be a private page. The defaults for those are 1) public 2) only for members. If 12345 is a user, you obviously have a public page for that user (named "home") according to your question. You might have added a private one, but the public page is still there